# A query won't generate random numbers

Tags: sql, postgresql, populate, generate-series

I have a table named `pool_hashrate` with columns: `id` (PK), `hashrate`, `network_id` (FK), `pool_id` (FK). I would like to populate them with a query:

```
insert into pool_hashrate (
    hashrate, network_id, pool_id
)
select
    i+i::double precision, i, i
from generate_series(0, 15) AS i;
```

...but it doesn't work. What am I missing?

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: I'm trying to run that in pgAdmin, so no errors at all. It just doesn't generate the records and I get rows affect -1.

Comment: after running the above, you selected from `pool_hashrate` and got no inserted records? after a query is run, pgadmin actually shows a message with number of rows affected by the query. what does the message say?

Comment: I inserted into `pool_hashrate` from `generate_series` and got no records inserted. pgAdmin shows `rows affected -1`